# Send Multicast Packet never received

Tags: c#, network-programming, multicast

Currently I have this C# code to open Socket Multicast connection.

```
  IPAddress destAddr = IPAddress.Parse(m_Address);

  m_Socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp); 
  m_Socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP,SocketOptionName.MulticastTimeToLive, m_TTL);

  m_EndPoint = new IPEndPoint(destAddr, m_Port);
  //Try to fix Network issue
  m_Socket.MulticastLoopback = true;
  m_Socket.Ttl = 255;
```

I connect using this code and Send Packet to Reciver,what happen is:

- On my device every thing work fine and receiver receive data without any problem.
- Using an other device on the same network using ethernet adapter packets go out (i see it in wire-shark) but never received !, same device using WiFi every thing working nice !.
- An other device on an other network using WiFi nothing work!

Any advice?
Again if I use Wire-Shark I see packets go out without problem!

Comment: Is multicast enabled on your network e.g. if you have a router between you and your destination, it will have to be configured to support multicast groups

Comment: me and my college on the same network (Router/Switch) .. etc. but it works for me but not for him,does Ethernet card have any role to do with multicast ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did figure it out
Me as a Sender use WiFi no problem happened, the problem comes up if sender use Cable from different Switch other than the switch receiver plugged on it !

So no thing to do in programming,it's **Switch settings** .
Please refer to this Cisco Tutorial for problem and solution
[Multicast does not work on the same vLan](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/switches/catalyst-6500-series-switches/68131-cat-multicast-prob.html)